# How to remove a character from at string at certain position from the end?

Tags: vb.net, string, trim

I have a string, for example:

```
    Dim str as string = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx£xxx£xxxx**£**xxxxxxxxxx
```

I want to remove `£` surrounded from `*` which is always at a certain position (11th for instance) from the end. The whole string is a long one, always change in size and cannot be counted from the start. I cannot use `Replace` as well, there may be same characters at other positions that I do not wish to remove.

---

**Solution:**

```
Dim rst As String = str.Remove(str.Length - 11, 1)
```

Comment: how about this one http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxbw3kwc.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Whoops, I dunno what I was thinking on that first part.

The correct version of the first part would be:

```
str = str.Substring(0, str.Len -13) + str.Substring(str.Len-11);
```

There also may be an overload for the `String.Delete` function that allows you to use a negative number to represent the number of characters from the end of the string -- I know that the C# equivalent does.

Comment: thanks Phillip .. you are quite right .. it is actually quite simple, when i know how though .. here what i have got ..
Dim rst As String = str.Remove(str.Length - 11, 1)

Comment: yeah, thats probably an even more straightforward way to do it.. good catch!

Comment: I thought I did Meta Knight !

Answer (score 1):

If its always going to be the 11th character from the end you can do this...

```
    Dim strTargetString As String = "xxxYxxxxxxxxxx"
    Dim strTargetString2 As String = "xxxxxxxYxxxxxxxxxx"

    Dim strResult As String = Mid(strTargetString, 1, (Len(strTargetString) - 11)) & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(strTargetString, 10)
    Dim strResult2 As String = Mid(strTargetString2, 1, (Len(strTargetString2) - 11)) & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(strTargetString, 10)
```

Note that [String.SubString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) is a more modern approach than Mid, but I use it out of preference and example.

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly straightforward with a regular expression replacement operation using look-ahead:

```
Dim str as String = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx£xxx£xxxx£xxxxxxxxxx"
Dim str2 as String = Regex.Replace(str, "£(?=.{10}$)", String.Empty)
```

This will target a single character followed by any ten characters then the end of the string and replace it with the `String.Empty` value (or just `""` if you'd prefer).